# Better way to start and stop process on a given port

Tags: ruby, linux, refactoring

My code works, but is there is a better solution?

I have an action to restart an external tool. Sometimes it either restarts or starts. I set the port to 12928. My checkobject has a method to get the PID from the system.

```
def pids
  %x{netstat -tanp | grep 12928}
end
```

With the method pid (below) I get the pid.

```
def pid
  /(?<pid>\d+)\//.match(pits.to_s)[:pid].to_i
end
```

To stop this service, I use:

```
Process.kill("SIGTERM",pid) 
Process.detach(pid)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a gem called `eye` (https://github.com/kostya/eye) which is inspired from Bluepill and God.

It looks quite good and i will give this a try.

If somebody interest in it, here is the example from the repository:

```
process :sample1 do
  pid_file '1.pid' 
  start_command 'ruby ./sample.rb'
  daemonize true
  stdall 'sample1.log'
end
```

For starting a job you do:

```
eye start sample1
```

For stopping this job you type:

```
eye stop sample1
```